# mkfs.ext3: Wrong medium type while trying to determine filesystem size

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, drbd, mkfs

When I try to format the /dev/drbd0 with mkfs.ext3 I get the error message:

> mkfs.ext3: Wrong medium type while trying to determine filesystem
>   size.

I found a solution here:

http://eng.eelcowesemann.nl/linux-unix/general/mkfs-ext3-wrong-medium-type-while-trying-to-determine-filesystem-size/

however if I execute the sueggested command drbdadm primary test, I got the following error:

> 0: State change failed: (-1) Multiple primaries not allowed by config
>   Command 'drbdsetup 0 primary' terminated with exit code 11

Any Ideas ?

Output from Command cat /proc/drbd:

```
version: 8.3.7 (api:88/proto:86-91)
srcversion: EE47D8BF18AC166BE219757
 0: cs:Connected ro:Secondary/Primary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r----
    ns:0 nr:0 dw:0 dr:0 al:0 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:b oos:0
```

and

drbd.conf:

```
 # You can find an example in  /usr/share/doc/drbd.../drbd.conf.example

    #include "drbd.d/global_common.conf";
    #include "drbd.d/*.res";

    global {
       usage-count yes;
   }
common {
 syncer {
   rate 100M;
 }
}
resource test {
 protocol C;
 handlers {
 pri-on-incon-degr "echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger ; halt -f";
 pri-lost-after-sb "echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger ; halt -f";
 local-io-error "echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger ; halt -f";
#  outdate-peer "/usr/sbin/drbd-peer-outdater";
 }
 startup {
   wfc-timeout         0;  ## Infinite!
   degr-wfc-timeout  120;  ## 2 minutes.
 }
 disk {
   on-io-error detach;
 }
 net {
   # timeout           60;
   # connect-int       10;
   # ping-int          10;
   # max-buffers     2048;
   # max-epoch-size  2048;
   # on-disconnect-reconnect;
  after-sb-0pri discard-younger-primary;
  after-sb-1pri consensus;
  after-sb-2pri disconnect;
  rr-conflict disconnect;
# allow-two-primaries;
 }
 syncer {
   rate 100M;
   al-extents 257;
 }
 on VOXDEMOSRV01 {
   device     /dev/drbd0;
   disk       /dev/sda6;
   address    192.168.1.134:7788;
   meta-disk /dev/sda7[0];
}
 on VOXDEMOSRVOWN01 {
   device     /dev/drbd0;
   disk       /dev/sda2;
   address    192.168.1.146:7788;
meta-disk /dev/sda5[0];
```

Comment: `cat /proc/drbd`? Also post your configuration file `/etc/drbd.conf` and/or `cat /etc/drbd.d/r0.res`?

Comment: I updated the webpage to mention the 'multiple primaries' message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> mkfs.ext3: Wrong medium type while trying to determine filesystem
>   size.

The reason is you are on secondary node and `/dev/drbd0` is read-only. Switch to primary node and try again.

Answer (score 2):

This problem may caused by the two drbd are secondary, you must make them one is primary the other is secondary. Below is my configuration:

```
#service drbd status
drbd driver loaded OK; device status:
version: 8.3.13 (api:88/proto:86-96)
GIT-hash: 83ca112086600faacab2f157bc5a9324f7bd7f77 build by dag@Build64R6, 2012-05-07 11:52:13
```

m:res  cs         ro                 ds                 p  mounted  fstype
1:r0   Connected  **Secondary/Primar**y  UpToDate/UpToDate  C